# Using Long to Sum variable rows VBA

Tags: vba, excel, variables, sum

I have the below snippet of a code which I wish to use to sum variable length rows

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = ActiveSheet.Range("Total").Row

With Worksheets("Post Implementation Costs")
    .Range("AD" & LR).Formula = "=Sum("AD7:AD"& LR - 1)"
End With
```

Where LR = 15 I wish the result to be `=SUM(AD:AD14)` however currently it returns `=Sum(AD7: & LR -1)`

Comment: I think you have a quotes problem

Comment: Also, I think in your post, you meant to get `=SUM(AD7:AD14)` and not `=SUM(AD:AD14)` as currently posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a little `"` placement issue, change your existing `Formula` line to :

```
.Range("AD" & LR).Formula = "=Sum(AD7:AD" & LR - 1 & ")"
```

Comment: Thanks! Knew it was something simple :)

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to avoid the quotation problem completely, you can use R1C1 notation and write the line as:

```
.Range("AD" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(R7C:R[-1]C)"
```

`R7` means row 7, `R[-1]` means the row before the current one, and `C` means the current column.

Comment: cute gimik :) still awake ?

Comment: @ShaiRado - was then - not now.